# why to use source devel/setup.bash

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not understand the functionality of sourcing a setup.bash file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251292/why-to-use-source-devel/setup.bash/) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By sourcing your setup.bash file, you are adding several environment variables that ROS needs in order to work. Some more information can be found in these related questions:

[what does source command actually do](http://answers.ros.org/question/188309/what-does-source-command-actually-do/)

[whats the meaning of the command source ...](http://answers.ros.org/question/124131/whats-the-meaning-of-the-command-source-optrosgroovysetupbash/)

Hope that clears things up a bit.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on 2017-01-05**:
Thanks. Your ans was helpful